# Is there a standard model of scar healing and if so what are its main stages?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery, wound, keloids

I have searched for a standard model of scar healing to learn how *dermal scar tissues are formulated and evolved* but didn't find one; rather, I found somewhat inconsistency between different definitions of that healing stage.

My prior research was limited because I don't have general access to plastic surgery literature but here is what I have understood so far

1. **Modeling:** A primal scar tissue, is being modeled (gradually formed) by gradually replacing (or by gradual transformation of) a closed wound tissue;
    The outcome is a significantly inflammated, swollen and red scar tissue;
   If predisposition exists it is in this stage that the scar tissue could become *hypertrophic* (keloid or at least ridged) or *atrophic* (sunken), while the predisposition should be diagnosed and treated or at leased prognosed by at least a plastic surgeon.
2. **Remodeling:**  The newly formed scar which is significantly inflammated, swollen and red, gradually heals by becoming somewhat less inflammated, less swollen (hence flatter) and less red;
   It is in this stage that daily anointing the scar tissue with a standardized good nutrient lotion is considered by some plastic surgeons as possibly improving the outcome of that stage.
3. **Maturation:** A phase in which a remodeled scar tissue becomes further flattened and generally lose all redness if any remained;
   It is after this stage that it's become adequate to go through scar revision therapies (laser/scalpel/anything else) if this are at all needed.

> The terms scar modeling([e1](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22scar+modeling%22&btnG=),[e2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5595592/)), scar remodeling([e2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1866977/)) and scar
>   maturation([e3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18453989)) are all used in medical literature while scar modeling is in 2020 almost not used in comparison to scar remodeling and scar maturation.

I often came across the claims that scar healing generally takes one year or two years; but I don't know of a convention or consensus and shouldn't strictly determine if there is one for all scars.

### Notes

<sub>I understand that any wound that is suspicious to evolve into a significant scar is best to be diagnosed as soon as possible by a plastic surgeon and that it is generally good to regularly follow up with plastic surgeon in all 3 stages I described to diagnose if complications exist and how to treat them, especially if there is such suspicion (and if the patient wants that).</sub>

<sub>I understand that when an organism is still in bodily growth, formed scars (as in stage 1) could be bigger than if bodily growth was ended, because the wound tissue or primal scar tissue might grow along with the body; thus, scar revision surgery (as performed with scalpel by a plastic surgeon) might be better postponed to after bodily growth was ended - depends on a particular case.</sub>

### My question

Is there a standard model of scar healing and if so what are its main stages?

<sub>An answer could explain in what stage (remodeling or maturation) it is good to do further treatments on scar tissue such as hair removal (if there is hair on scar), scar flattening (if the scar can be further flattened), *scar tattooing in body color* and so forth.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104784/discussion-on-question-by-johndoea-is-there-a-standard-model-of-scar-healing-and).

Comment: Probably because you edited it. Editing it causes the question to get moved to the top of the active list, and that means more people will see it who didn't see it previously. That's the reason more people saw it, but I don't know the reason for the downvote. You've since improved the question with better prior research.